# Selection of distinct rows in text file using Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I am looking to delete distinct rows from a text file using PowerShell. Here is the scenario:

I have a text file named **test123** with the below content:

```
%A ABC

%B ABC1

%B ABC2

%B ABC3

%B ABC4

%A DEF
```

My PowerShell  script should search `% A ABC` and delete the rows starting with `%B ABC1` until `%B ABC4`. So far, I am able to write only the below code:

```
get-content C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\test123.txt | Select-String -pattern  "ABC"
```

and it returns

```
%A ABC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
$keep = $true
Get-Content test123.xer | where {
  if ( $_ -like "*ABC*" ) {
    $keep = $false
  } elseif ( -not $keep -and $_.StartsWith("%A") ) {
    $keep = $true
  }
 $keep
} | Set-Content output.xer
```

Answer (score 0):

i suspect that you have left out some important things [*grin*], but this does what you describe.

what it does ...

- fakes reading in a plain text file as an array of lines
  replace this with your preferred source - pro'ly `Get-Content`.
- defines the pattern to skip
- filters the lines of text for those that `-notmatch` the skip pattern
- sends the "keep this" lines to the `$Results` collection
- displays that on the screen

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
%A ABC
%B ABC1
%B ABC2
%B ABC3
%B ABC4
%A DEF
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file

$SkipThisPattern = 'B ABC'

$Results = $InStuff |
    Where-Object {
        $_ -notmatch $SkipThisPattern
        }

$Results
```

output ...

```
%A ABC
%A DEF
```

Comment: Thanks Lee ! Sorry for my lack of knowledge here however when I am trying to use Get-Content like this @'(Get-Content C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\test123.txt | Select-String -pattern  "%A ABC ")'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine.. I am getting error. Am I am doing something wrong here ..

Comment: @AnshulGupta - what is the `@'(your code here)'@` about? if you read the comment you will see that the `region/endregion` stuff is just a way to embed test data in the script. replace ALL of that `region/endregion` area with `$InStuff = Get-Content $PathToYourFIle`. [*grin*]